# Route every request to a given controller unless another controller is specified

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to achieve the following behavior: `http://example.com/anything` should pass `anything` to a default controller (namely, "category_browser"), unless `anything` is a controller name.

The first part is easily achieved with this line in `config/routes.php`:

```
$route[':any'] = "category_browser";
```

while I did not manage to get the second one to work.

I would really appreciate any input.

Other info: the number of controllers is pretty small; writing an options line for each of them is an option; they should be passed parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this: 
http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/CodeIgniter-Route-Everything-except-these-Controllers

```
$route['^(?!controller|controller|controller)\S*'] = "article/$1";
```

Comment: Unbelievable! You, <subject name here>, must be the pride of <subject hometown here>!

Comment: If category browser is the default controller you shouldn't need to worry about it. Unless of course one of your categories is sharing a name with a controller.

Comment: @jim. I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: sorry forgot this. Please remove the "$1" at the end; it will give a 404.

Answer (score 1):

create a master controller that you point everything to. in the master controller, check if the set controller name exists, if so, run it, if not, call category_browser using controller name as method instead.

Comment: Oh wait a sec. feeling even dumber for not realizing that, actually, you can't call a controller within a controller in CI, that is a necessity to use this solution.